# How would you set up a long-exposure shot from the computer?

Tags: software, long-exposure, microscopy

I just got a USB digital microscope and I would like to setup a long exposure experiment (~5 minute capture). Unfortunately, I have no clue what software I need to have to set up a long exposure shot. I'm not even sure how to begin to search for such information.

I have a celestron Handheld microscope using Windows 7.

Comment: @aJhenderson, wouldn't microphotography fall under the realm of photography? I could just easily have said macrophotography instead.

Comment: Could you provide the model number?   44302-A, the Deluse Handheld Digital Microscope?  If so, it comes with an built-in sensor and Windows software.  Or is it another Celestron product?  Their support site has more info.

Comment: I have 44302-B. The Windows software has capture software but it doesn't allow for time exposure.

Comment: So, are you asking if someone can modify their capture software? Or, are you wondering if someone has written their own interface and capture software to the microscope?   If so, you may want to ask in one of the coder stackexchanges.   However, if you also have an optical microscope and wanted to attach a DSLR/Mirror-less/ILC camera to capture long exposures, this is a perfectly good stackexchange for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a video and extract individual frames from that. You can then blend the frames together into one long exposure (For instance, in photoshop you can use Load Files into Stack and after converting it into a smart object stack you can set the stack mode to Mean, although you'll need a powerful computer for this method).

You should probably take the video at a low FPS to minimize the time needed to merge the frames together.

There's an automatic python script which can do all of this for you - http://www.eliteraspberries.com/blog/2013/01/simulate-long-exposure-photography-with-opencv.html

Comment: Won't exactly work for my purposes. My signal to noise isn't very high so I really do need the longer exposure time.

Comment: The mean/median blend should help pretty much eliminate any noise

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean for a long exposure. Normally that is a single photo and the movement is captured as a blured trail.

Probably you are refering to a time lapse capture. Probably filming the full 5 mins and reproduce it in 1 minute.

Try using a screen capture software. The most popular i think is http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html you have to make some texts to configure the size of the output file, frame rate, etc.

You can configure it as a time lapse or a real time video.

If you need the blured result as the real long term exposition I agree with the option provided in user22723 to merge all the frames in a program like photoshp, starting with this same video.